# Is it possible to use django Piston on Google AppEngine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-piston

I haven't been able to do so due to all sort of missing dependencies (mainly, I think the problem is in the authentication code which relies on django stuff that is not available on AppEngine)

I was wondering if anyone patched\forked piston to get it working on AppEngine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem with Piston and AppEngine is mainly when it comes to the authentication code.
So, I managed to port Piston to AppEngine doing the following:

1. I'm using the [app-engine-patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) project which integrates django's authentication framework with Google AppEngine
2. I forked Piston and removed all the OAuth authentication code and models (in authentication.py). Its probably not too complicated to convert the model and auth code but as I don't need it I didn't bother...

Answer (score 5):

http://bitbucket.org/gumptioncom/django-piston-app-engine/

Answer (score 1):

I've forked django-oauth, to make it compatible with app-engine-patch. So it could eventually be used with [django-piston-app-engine](http://bitbucket.org/gumptioncom/django-piston-app-engine/).

http://bitbucket.org/mtourne/django-oauth-appengine/